# Formik Yup - I am unable to validate data within an Object based on data from another object

Tags: formik, yup

I am unable to validate data within an Object based on data from another object.

```
const schema1 = Yup.object().shape({
  value: Yup.number(),
  obj1: Yup.object().shape({
    teste: Yup.boolean(),
  }),
});
```

I need to validate if the value field is 1, the test field must be mandatory.
How should I proceed?

However, when trying to pass Yup.ref or .when with the "value" field, it does not find the value.